# Css positioning an image on side of a text in a SEO friendly manner

Tags: css, html, seo

I have this HTML code.

I need visualize the image on the TOP-RIGHT side of my Text. I cannot move the DIV containing the image before the first paragraph and apply `float`.

My aim is to display the image on top together with the text but leaving the HTML code for the image last in page (SEO reasons).

Any idea how to fix it? Thanks

```
<div>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <div>
         <img src="img.gif" alt="My Image" />
     </div>
</div>
```

---

```
some text here    +----+
some text here    |img |
some text here    +----+
some text here
some text here
```

---

PS: The lenght of the Text could be variable.

Comment: position:relative; and then negative top and left values?

Comment: The lenght of the Text could be variable, your solution could work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/patonar/jxha3/

Comment: I tried but the text should go under the image after the image (float behavior) . Any idea? Maybe using jQuery could help?

Comment: I tested once again your solution, I confirm it is working many thanks for your help on this!

Comment: The text will go over the image given a long paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/jxha3/1/

By positioning the image to the right (float) that way you only need to change overall width of UL, the image then will always stay in that fixed position to the right of the text, regardless of the length :)

Comment: text should go under the image like float behavior and I must use <p> I cannot use <ul><li>. Any idea? Thanks for now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/sikusikucom/8GR37/

Comment: The idea is to absolute-position the image and set enough (right) margin for the paragraphs. This way the layout won't break regardless of the length of `<p>`.